# Running an animation before JQuery load()

Tags: jquery, ajax, load

I'm trying to take advantage of JQuery's `load()` function and I'm puzzled as to why an animation won't take place *before* the load request.

For example, if I have a script that says:

```
$('#clickme').click(function() {
    $('#content').slideUp(500);
    $('#content').slideDown(500);
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/593cC/

Then, that's exactly what happens.  It slides up, then slides down.  But, if I place a `load()` function in between those two lines, it ignores the first animation line altogether and just carries out with the rest of the lines.

```
$('#clickme').click(function() {
    $('#content').slideUp(500);
    $('#content').load('myotherpage.php').hide();
    $('#content').slideDown(500);
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/593cC/1/

Why is this?  I have tried putting a `delay()` on the operations with no success. What can I do to prevent this so my events have a nice effect going in and out?

Many thanks, SO

Comment: They're probably being run synchronously

Comment: Probably.  I always thought JQuery took orders in succession though...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to use `load` inside callback of your `slideUp` function:

```
$('#content').slideUp(500 ,function() {
    $('#content').load('myotherpage.php').hide();
});
```

[**Updated Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/593cC/3/)

Comment: Nice.  That's a great tip.  I ended up nesting the slideDown() function as a callback function after the load, too, ensuring everything went in order.  Will mark as accepted.  Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

It does properly slideUp, however, since .load empties the element, it appears as though it happens instantly because the element's height all of a sudden becomes 0+padding.

I'd suggest not using .load here:

```
$('#clickme').click(function() {
    // get data
    var request = $.get("myotherpage.php");
    $('#content').slideUp(500,function(){
        // when request is done AND the element is hidden, apply content and slide it back down.
        request.done(function(html){
            $('#content').html( $.parseHTML(html) ).slideDown(500);
        });
    });
});
```

This results in there being no delay between slideUp and slideDown as long as the request takes less than 500ms.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$('#content').slideUp(500).load('myotherpage.php', function () {
    $('#content').slideDown(500);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Place your load inside `slideup` callback and `slidedown` inside the callback for load (as it is asynchronous).  http://jsfiddle.net/cwSXa/

[.load()](http://api.jquery.com/load/)

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $('#clickme').click(function () {
        $('#content').slideUp(500, function () {
            $('#content').load('myotherpage.php', function () {
                $('#content').slideDown(500);
            });
        });
   });
});
```